Why would my PERN web applicaton deployed with Render only have the Server running and not the Client?
I'm running into an issue while trying to deploy my PERN application. The database is already set up and linked. The deployment process is not failing, but when you follow the link to the site it only is showing the json responses to the servers routes.
These are the scripts that I am using in my applications main package.json:
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build && cd ../backend && npm install",
"start": "node backend/server.js"
},

The build and start commands are what are used in the deployment. Here is how I am trying to connect my backend to the dist directory's index.html file in backend/server.js:
'''
"use strict";

/** Server start up logic */
// Imports
const express = require('express');
const app = require("./app");
const { PORT } = require("./config");
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
   console.log(`Started on Port:${PORT}`);
})

Since I am a novice, I don't know what else may be useful to solve this problem. So please let me know where other trouble areas may be.
